# Aligning a unordered list in the center of the page [New issue]

Tags: html, css

So my issue here is that i want my text to show in the dead center of the page. I've been trying to manually align it but that seems like a bad way of doing it. I want it so that even if the webpage is resized to be smaller or the user is using a smaller screen, the unordered list will show in the dead center of the screen. What I've tried so far doesn't move with the background and is aligned very poorly.
HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Web_v2/css/Style.css">
<head><title>Company</title></head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>about us</li>
<li>Who we are</li>
<li>Contact us</li>


</ul>

</nav>

</body>

    <div id="bg">
<img src="../Web_v2/Assets/bg.jpg">
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
#bg img{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
nav{
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 20;

}
```

EDIT: Thanks for all the helpful answers, but I'm still having an issue.

Problem 1: When the page is resized, the text moves up and down. I want it sitting around the top of the mountain: http://gyazo.com/8c7dc29c17dab86186cf4bfde4eb1a18
- It should look like this:http://gyazo.com/644b3c072e7befffaf08d412a894bbb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple code for making unordered list centralized in whole page.

Give style to your nav tag as follow:

```
nav{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

And Give style to your ul tag as below:

```
ul{
   float:none;
   margin:35% auto auto;
   width:200px;
   list-style:none;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that worked well for putting it on the center of the page, but i ran into some separate issues. Would you mind looking at the post and seeing if you can help out?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the  in a  and set CSS rules to center text.

For example:

```
<div id="centerme">
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>about us</li>
          <li>Who we are</li>
          <li>Contact us</li>   
        </ul> 
    </nav>
</div>

CSS:

#centerme {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: When you use: text-align in the nav tag itself using CSS, you are just aligning the text in the individual nav, not the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to center it just horizontally, but if that's the case you can check out what I did here (including random background image!): http://jsfiddle.net/2o2a3a6t/1/

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Who We Are</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>


html{
    background: url('http://bit.ly/1Efu4Mc') no-repeat center center;
    height: 100%;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```